# Ubuntu 16.04 can't wakeup on macbook pro 11,3

Tags: suspend, macbook-pro, wakeup

I use ubuntu 16.04. I close my lid and ubuntu goes to suspend, but after opennig lid it doesn't wake up -- black screen, so I can reboot my macbook only by holding reboot button. Can somebody help me please?

Answer (score 0):

This is a known I/O problem with Macbook pros and usually has nothing to do with the operating systems. Usually the manufacturer's (Apples's) solution would be to replace that circuit for a couple of hundred dollars. However, if you are running ubuntu, you are in luck, because you can tell your machine not to go to sleep when the lid is closed. To do so,

You need to edit a file, named `logind.conf` in `/etc/systemd/logind.conf` , but it can be edited using this command in your terminal: s`udo -H gedit /etc/systemd/logind.conf`
At the bottom of the text, add: `HandleLidSwitch=ignore`
Execute this coomand to restart your systemd daemon and have the command settle in, otherwise it won't work. **sudo service systemd-logind restart** (for ubuntu 15+)
I strongly advise you don't run your Macbook pro on closed lid for a long time as it will cause ventilation problems and quickly heats up the system.